# Angular phone directive is not leaving model empty when deleting whole value. Also, always allows an additional digit

Tags: angular

I have this directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPhoneMask]'
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective {

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    const newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.onInputChange(newVal, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }
  

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
}
```

This is an example of an input using it:

```
    <input
      (blur)="validateOther()"
      id="otherPhone"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCommunicationMethod.value"
      placeholder="Enter phone"
      appPhoneMask
      class="form-control w-50"
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': showOtherErrorMsg}"
    />
```

The directive works mostly fine, but I'm having two issues. One is that when I delete everything via backspace, it still leaves a value in the model. It doesn't delete it completely. Additionally, when I write more than 10 digits, the model always allows one more digit than it should. Oh and another problem I'm having is that if I write anything that is not a number, it doesn't show up in the input, but it is saved in the model. Can anyone help me with these issues?

Answer (score 2):

### > "It doesn't delete it completely"

From your code:

```js
    @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
    keydownBackspace(event) {
        this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
    }
```

It means that `event.target.value` holds the value of the input field *before* the backspace event has removed the character. So... when deleting the last character, the old value (with one character) is still passed to `onInputChange` function.

You might need to remove that character:

```js
    @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
    keydownBackspace(event) {
        const newVal = event.target.value.slice(0, -1); // Remove last character
        this.onInputChange(newVal, true);
    }
```

### > "the model always allows one more digit than it should"

I suspect the string length is being restricted to 10 characters *after* you have potentially added an extra character. That extra character is added in the conditions where you are checking if the length of `newVal` is less than or equal to certain values (the "formatting" part).

Add a `newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);` just before applying formatting.

### > it doesn't show up in the input, but it is saved in the model

You do compute a `newVal` in `onModelChange`: `const newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');`

But you do not write it to the model, that would need a `this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);`.
And this, done right after removing non-numeric characters.

See as an example "[Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://indepth.dev/posts/1055/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms)" by [Max Koretskyi](https://twitter.com/@maxkoretskyi).

---

Using a `processInput()` function which centralizes input processing and is used by `ngModelChange`, `keydown.backspace`, and `blur` handlers, this code updates both the `valueAccessor` and the linked form control (if any):

You can also try and manually trigger change detection in Angular. That will force Angular to update the view whenever changes are made to the model. That can be done using Angular's []`ChangeDetectorRef` service](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPhoneMask]'
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective {

  private isUpdating = false;

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    if (!this.isUpdating) {
      this.onInputChange(event, false);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    this.isUpdating = true;
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();  // Trigger change detection manually
    this.isUpdating = false;
  }
}
```

The [`changeDetector.detectChanges();`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges) line should trigger Angular's change detection, forcing the view to update with the new value right away, which should in turn apply the formatting and limit the input to 10 digits while typing.

Do make sure your `validateOther()` method also calls `this.selectedCommunicationMethod.value.replace(/\D/g, '')` to ensure non-numeric characters do not get into the model.

See also "**[ngModel & Two way Data binding in Angular](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ngmodel-two-way-data-binding-in-angular/)**".

The `this.isUpdating = true;` set at the beginning of the `processInput` method and reset it back to `false` at the end should help detect the update phase. There is also a guard at the beginning of `onModelChange` to return early if `this.isUpdating` is `true`.

Moreover, when setting the value of the control, the configuration object with `emitEvent` is set to `false`. This will prevent Angular from emitting a new `ngModelChange` event, breaking the potential cycle that would result in a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added these changes to the directive but I'm still having the same issue. What I'm doing is writing an `a` in the input. It doesn't show up in the input as it should. However, I'm console logging the value of the model on the blur method, and the a is appearing in the model. The issue with the 11 digits also wasn't fixed. Curiously enough, when I log values on the backspace, newVal does appear empty. It just seems like it isn't writing that newVal to the model.

Comment: I suspect this is the [Angular NgModel two-way data binding](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ngmodel-two-way-data-binding-in-angular/) that I did not implement correctly. I cannot fully test the code, but I have edited the answer to propose a slightly altered code. Let me know if it works better.

Comment: I changed it but it seems to be going on an infinite loop, since I get the maximum call stack exceeded error on console.

Comment: @plasmy I suppose there is a mutual calling between `ngModelChange` and `setValue`, creating a circular call stack that leads to a stack overflow. I have updated the code to try and prevent that.

Comment: So close! Now it allows  unlimited entries in the input box, and also it doesn't apply the formatting (the parenthesis). But the model does delete everything, and if I click outside the input box it does show the formatting and it limits to 10 digits. The only problem now is while typing. You've been very kind and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @plasmy Interesting (and I apologize, I cannot properly test this code, only make suggestion): new suggestion, triggering the update manually, through [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges): I have updated the answer.